# Wordpress Main Menu with dynamic url

Tags: custom-taxonomy, menus

I am having taxonomy in custom post type like cities Las Vegas,Los Angeles,Nashvile etc. I am having main menu like Home About Us (http://www.example.com/about-us) and Contact.

Now When i am on Nashvile Category Page i want to generate about us link like ( http://www.example.com/nashvile/about-su)  is it achievable in wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter menu items with the [wp_nav_menu hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_nav_menu/)